# Can't run ls -e via SFTP

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, sftp

I'm trying to execute the command `ls -e` using a SFTP connection, but -e option is not available.

I need to get a date/time from creation file, example "Aug 11 19:36:40 2017"

I've already used the `ls -e` using a SSH connection, but due some restrictions I can't use this connection.

`ls -l` is not a good solution, because files older than 1 year I won't get information about hours and seconds.

I'm using a shell script with sftp command to connect to remote server.

Can someone help me with this situation?

Comment: Could you possibly clarify the client software you are using?

Comment: I'm not using any specific client. I'm just using shell script and using the sftp command to connect to remote servers.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that information. Please see [ask] and take our [tour].

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSH `sftp` client does not support printing a full timestamp.

If you want to get a full file timestamp from an SFTP/SSH server, you have these options:

- Use a different SFTP client, like `lftp` (as the [answer by @gogators](https://superuser.com/q/1268173/213663#1268259) shows).
- Use an SFTP library in some scripting language, like Perl, Python, PHP, etc.
- If you have an shell access, use it to execute `ls --full-time` command on the server (or equivalent, if the server is not *nix-based). *I'm aware that you have tried this already.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lftp`'s `cls` command over an sftp connection to format the timestamps locally. The `cls` command has a `--time-style=STYLE` option. The format for `STYLE` is the same as the `date` command. For example:

```
lftp sftp://user@sftp.server.org
lftp sftp.server.org:~> cls -l --time-style=%FT%T file.txt
-rw-r-----   1 user   group      2032 2014-10-12T10:07:58 file.txt
```